# how to transfer files from canon cameras over wifi?

Tags: wifi, canon

Canon cameras like powershot s120 and sx600hs have wifi capability. How could that be used with linux to transfer images and videos without involving Windows in any way?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Can you be more precise as to what you're asking (for example, perhaps you have a Canon S120 and you've tried but got nowhere fast)?

Comment: Yes, I tried to find a way to retrieve images from S120 and SX600HS, but could not find a way to do that on Linux. Canon has a Windows/Mac software/driver for this: http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/8201651300.html , and apparently there are some cameras that might work with gPhoto, but not recent Canon cameras: http://gphoto-software.10949.n7.nabble.com/canon-powershot-a3500-IS-wifi-camera-td14027.html

Comment: I am also interested, since I have also a Canon.  Seems that gPhoto may do the job, at least for the S120 which is supported.  Follow http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php . Here the Ubuntu help for gPhoto http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/gphoto , and for a GUI http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/gtkam ... I will continue to investigate.  If you succeed, please answer your own question.

Comment: If this is working in Windows, file transfer would use `samba`. How far do you get when you start a `samba` shared folder on your machine and connecting to it from the camera?

Comment: It's not using SMB, as far as I know - there were reports about PTPIP being used, but in the meantime a tool called "Airnef" has appeared that claims to support Canon cameras, too - will have to try it out: http://www.testcams.com/airnef/

Comment: unfortunately, getting the same GUID error as described in this thread : http://testcams.com/blog/forums/topic/guid-problem-with-canon-and-linux/

Answer (score 6):

Try [AirNEF](http://www.testcams.com/airnef/)

Specs say:

```
All Canon Cameras with WiFi:
 Select Images in Camera: No
 Select Images on Computer: Yes
 Realtime Download: Yes
```

Works very well for my WiFi equipped Nikon on OSX.

However one word of caution; picture size does matter! Trying to pull 24MP RAW images through WiFi is not recommended.

Using this method to transfer your pictures from the camera to your computer as a batch operation is questionable. A card reader will most likely accomplish this quicker.

IMHO it is better suited to tethered shooting, i.e. 'realtime download' in AirNEF speak.

I have done some tests with tethered shooting using JPG+RAW mode in the camera - transferring only the JPG. Considering the limitations of the transfer speed it works well - need to set the JPG to as small as you can accept, then use a card reader to grab the RAWs when you're done.

One small 'problem' is how to display the images as they arrive in the computer though. I have as I said tried it and I admit I did not put too much work into this end, but each image opened in its own window which quickly became messy.

Anyway, my $0.02.

Daniel